# How to determine position of ball with android phone use opencv

Tags: android, opencv

I am a newbie in opencv and i have a project with opencv in android.
I try to find real position of ball like a below picture

[image]

In this picture, android phone is attach in front of my mobile robot and try to find d and w.
I think maybe i will use cabliration for camera to find focal length and then i can use this fomular :

```
focal length = (Real heigh of ball * distance from camera to ball) / number of pixel height of ball in phone
```

However, with this way, i just find d, i don't know how to find w. Please give me a way that find w

Comment: that angle between d/w is a mirror? in that case you're finding d+w, not just d

Comment: Yes, i would like to find both of d and w, But i don't know how to find them, i use opencv in android

Comment: unless that mirror has a border or something on it, you can't detect it - the camera will only see what the mirror is reflecting, not the mirror itself. as such, any calculations you do on the ball's apparent size will ALWAYS return d+w as the distance.

Comment: I can see ball in screen of my phone, i can find x,y position(pixel) in my screen, moreover if i use cabliration i can find d, d is distance from camera to ball. However, when ball move to right, I would like to know w

Comment: No border,no thing, just have a mobile robot with camera of andoird phone and ball

Comment: but are you seeing what's in the mirror, or are you directly seeing the ball? your diagram is not clear at all on that point.

Comment: I still see ball in mirror, but it locate in right side of screen

Comment: then if your only view of the ball is through the mirror, you canNOT tell the difference between the ball moving 5 feet away from the mirror, or the mirror moving 5 feet away from the camera. all you see is that the ball got smaller by 5 feet worth of distance. in both cases the ball will get visually smaller by 5 feet, but it is impossible to tell which moved.

Comment: I am understand your idea but in this link, i see the way how to find distance from camera to ball use opencv.: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/

Comment: there no mirror in there. without knowing the distance from your camera to the mirror, you cannot determine ANYTHING about what `w` is, only the entire `d+w`

Comment: Do you have a facebook, would you please give me your facebook and let me tell you about my idea. I try to make a mobile robot tracking ball but there is some problem that i can't find someone who can help me to solve that